# List of Tuples to DF (unequal length tuples)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Have an interesting problem where there is a dictionary in the following format:

```
test = {'A': [(1,2),(3,4)],
        'B': [(1,2),(5,6),(7,8)]}
```

For each key in the dictionary, they share some values (first always), but there are a different number of tuples in each list.

Ultimately, my goal is to represent the data in this format:

```
     1 3 5 7
  A  2 4 - - 
  B  2 - 6 8
```

Is there a smart way to convert these common elements in the values of the dictionary to a column of a data frame?

What I was thinking to get the lists to be of equal length was the following:

```
#get all the unique first elements of the dictionary
unique=[]
for i in test.values():
    for j in i:
        unique.append(j[0])

unique = set(unique)

values_of_A = test['A']

#I thought this would loop through each tuple in the list and check if its 
#first value is in the list of unique elements; otherwise, it will print
#0. However, it comes up with a blank list...
full_list = [0 for i, v in enumerate(values_of_A) if v[0] not in unique]
```

Thanks as always!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about how you want the data in `test` to be transformed?  It's not immediately clear what the logic in producing the output should be.

Comment: Yes - was just trying to scan all of the tuples and put the unique elements in the first position across all tuples as the column headers, then the dictionary keys as the first column and the values of the table would be the value associated with that match. Not sure if that's helpful, but maybe the picture above helps with words to it. If not, let me know. Either way, juanpa's solution was perfect!

Comment: Glad to hear that @juanpa.arrivillaga's solution worked - but note that the output you specified doesn't match it.  (That's not a criticism of the answer, which I've upvoted).

Comment: Ah yes - mistake on my part with the 6 and 8 - you guys don't miss a thing. I will adjust the question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can probably just munge it and use the `from_dict` alternative constructor:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k:dict(v) for k,v in test.items()}, orient='index')
   1    3    5    7
A  2  4.0  NaN  NaN
B  2  NaN  6.0  8.0
>>>
```

Comment: Amazingly efficient and exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: @user6142489 your welcome. Note, in the future, you can build a set directly, something like `unique = set()` and then in your for-loop `unique.add(j[0])`

Comment: Done! Thanks again!